# Python packages are getting installed as UNKNOWN using pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install some packages like pycadf. It's failing with the below error:

```
Searching for pycadf>=0.4.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycadf/
Best match: pycadf 0.5.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycadf/pycadf-0.5.1.tar.gz#md5=0386d95acb2045231fbcbe12fcaa2779
Processing pycadf-0.5.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-93QzI3/pycadf-0.5.1/setup.cfg
Running pycadf-0.5.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-93QzI3/pycadf-0.5.1/egg-dist-tmp-DumyVX
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'pbr'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding UNKNOWN 0.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
error: Could not find required distribution pycadf>=0.4.1
```

Looks like it gets the package from the pypi, installs it as "UNKNOWN". It doesn't happen with every package. setuptools-5.5.1 is installed in my environment.

Any inputs to solve will be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I had, what looks like, the same problem. The solution for me was to update setuptools.

Comment: This was what I needed. I had a package downgrade setuptools and I didn't notice.

Comment: For me, it was to upgrade `pip` via `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` to 23.3.1.